# Wordpress Post featured image responsive issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following problem with my wordpress site. In my blog section, where a list of all blogposts is shown, my featured images are of bad quality because of the responsive images option Wordpress implements. This is what my code looks like:

```
    <div class="post-thumb"><a href="http://www.example.com/mypost">
    <img width="300" height="75" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/img-300x75.jpeg" class="alignleft wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/img-300x75.jpeg 300w, http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/img-768x192.jpeg 768w, http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/img-1024x256.jpeg 1024w, http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/img.jpeg 1400w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
    </a></div>
```

If I change the 'sizes' element in my console and the maximum width to a much higher number than 300px (e.g. 3000px), my image shows in the quality it is supposed to be. But now my site, which is full width, only scales an image of 300px. I currently do not know where to change this element in my theme.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello try display images in full size in your theme:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
```

My template always displays images in full resolution.

Or you can try change post thubnail size from Admin Panel and refresh images with plugin again (i dont remember plugin name now).

Style (or min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%;):

```
<style type="text/css">
.post-thumb img{
    padding: 5px; float: left; width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; box-sizing: border-box;
}   
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I have added the php code in the functions.php file but it didn't do the trick. It might be another setting somewhere else. Unfortunatly CSS changes aren't helping me out. They get overwritten by the 'max-width' in the sizes tag. I did find the folowing line in my functions.php: "add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');" It might be that the filesize gets overwritten somewhere.

Comment: width: 100% !important;  I forgot to add :) but php you need set in page template where you want display big images

Comment: add to style in footer for example 
 
width: 100% !important;

Comment: !important; force override atribute

Comment: Found two interesting links about the [srcset](https://martinwolf.org/blog/2016/02/how-to-edit-srcset-attribute-in-wordpress-responsive-images) and [responsive image support](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211375/how-do-i-disable-responsive-images-in-wp-4-4/211376#211376). Removing the support does remove the sizes attribute, but defaults on a 300px width image, as we can see in my code above in the src tab. Css won't work in this case because the default image is low resolution and results in a bad quality image. I'll keep on looking!

Comment: Regenerate image size :) i sent you  link with tutorial

Comment: or search this code in template files and change to your size

Comment: Will try it later this week! Thank you for your help already :)

Comment: Regenerating the images worked! Thank you so much for providing me a solution.